# SQL - Combine multiple rows data into comma seperate result

Tags: sql, db2

Using SQL query

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT ',' + DIMENSION
                FROM FSP_SEL_DATA
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

I am trying to combine multiple row' s data DIMENSION of table `FSP_SEL_DATA` into comma separate result but it is returning the below error:

> An unexpected token "XML PATH(''" was found following "
>                 FOR  ".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.59.81

Does anyone know how to correct ?

Comment: What database are you using?  My guess is SQL Server?

Comment: @JustinCave , it' s DB2.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ', ' + CAST(DIMENSION AS VARCHAR(20))
        FROM FSP_SEL_DATA        
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS DIMENSION
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24b49/2) to view result

Comment: Whats down vote for? Its working perfectly with the working fiddle.

Comment: Hi Downvoter. Please comment for the reason of downvote.

Comment: Hi Sarath, I tried above query however it returned same error message - An unexpected token "XML PATH(''" was found following "EL_DATA
        FOR".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.59.81

Database is DB2 and I am trying to execute this query from Eclipse - NWDS.

Comment: I have pasted code for SQL Server. Which DB are you using?